# 3D Cartesian Transformation

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, rigid-transformation

I have a tetrahedron in a 3D Cartesian space. 
It has two orientations.
I know the same three vertices positions (xyz) in the first orientation and the second orientation.
I know the position of the fourth point (xyz) in one orientation, and want to calculate it in the second.
I understand this requires using rotation matrices or quaterions. The rotation matrix method seems the most user friendly. There seem to be quite a few previous posts on this, which have provided some good insight into the best approach. It seems my approach should be along the following lines: (1) Work out the center of rotation for the object. (2) Work out the precise rotation of the object about the x,y and z axes, passing through this point. (3) Use a rotation matrix to derive the position of the fourth point in its new orientation.
Would somebody be kind enough to confirm I am on the right lines with this approach? Many Thanks. James.

Comment: Does the transformation involve a translation as well as a rotation?  If it does, you will have to use a homogeneous transformation not just a rotation.

Comment: Yes it does. I was under the impression that any rotation and translation could be reduced to just a rotation about a specific point - now you mention this though I am not sure I am correct...

Comment: Ive been sat here scribbling some pictures out - I'm fairly sure everything except pure translation can be defined in rotational terms about a given axis - You can always use the perpendicular bisection method to find the center in any given plane, unless the situation is pure translation, where the bisectors will never intersect. Let me know if i'm wrong. Cheers

Comment: you are correct about any rigid motion being a rotation and translation about an axis.  This is called a *screw* motion.  If no one answers I will try to answer this question tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say your tetrahedron with the four known vertices (Lets call it $T_A$) is given by four points $\{\mathbf a_1, \mathbf a_2, \mathbf a_3, \mathbf a_4\}$ and the other (Lets call it $T_B$) has a face corresponding to the first three points defined by $\{\mathbf b_1, \mathbf b_2, \mathbf b_3 \}$.  You want to find $\mathbf b_4$ which corresponds to the fourth vertex of $T_B$.  Lets assume that we store the $x$, $y$, and $z$ values of each of these points in a $3\times 1$ vector as $[x, y, z]^T$.  Let's denote the base coordinate system with subscript $0$.  Let's assume that each tetrahedron has a local coordinate system attached to it denoted by subscript $A$ and $B$.  Each of these local coordinate systems is defined as follows:

- The origin of $A$ is given by $\mathbf a_1$ and the origin of $B$ is given by $\mathbf b_1$.
- The local $x$-axis ($\mathbf x_A$ and $\mathbf x_B$) of each system points from $\mathbf a_1$ toward $\mathbf a_2$ for $A$, similarly for $B$.
- The local $y$-axis ($\mathbf y_A$ and $\mathbf y_B$) of each system is co-planar with $x_A$ and $x_B$ respectively and in the plane swept out by $\mathbf a_2$ and $\mathbf b_2$ respectively.
- The local $z$-axis ($\mathbf z_A$ and $\mathbf z_B$) is defined by $\mathbf x_A \times \mathbf y_A$ and by $\mathbf x_B \times \mathbf y_B$ respectively.

We can then define the needed axes as follows:
$$\mathbf x_A  = \frac{\mathbf a_2 - \mathbf a_1}{\|\mathbf a_2 - \mathbf a_1\|}$$
$$\mathbf z_A  = \frac{\mathbf x_A \times (\mathbf a_3- \mathbf a_1)}{\|\mathbf x_A \times (\mathbf a_3- \mathbf a_1)\|}$$

$$\mathbf y_A  = \mathbf z_A \times \mathbf x_A$$

Do the same for $B$.

Now we can define the rotation matrix from $A$ back to the base coordinate system as

$$\mathbf R_0^A = \left[ \begin{array}{ccc} \mathbf x_A & \mathbf y_A  & \mathbf z_A \end{array} \right].$$

Again, do the same for $B$.

Now we define a *homogeneous transformation* from $A$ back to the base coordinate system as follows

$$\mathbf H_0^A = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} 
\mathbf R_0^A & \mathbf a_1  \\
 \mathbf 0^T &  1 
\end{array} \right].$$

Do the same for $B$.

Now to transfer a point represented in the frame $A$ to the base coordinate system, use the transformation as follows:

$$\mathbf v_0 = \mathbf H_0^A \left[ \begin{array}{c} 
\mathbf v_A   \\
   1 
\end{array} \right].$$

Finally we can compute our unknown point as follows

$$\left[ \begin{array}{c} 
\mathbf b_4 \\
1
\end{array}\right]
= \mathbf H_0^B (\mathbf H_0^A)^{-1} \left[ \begin{array}{c} 
\mathbf a_4   \\
   1 
\end{array} \right].$$